# Create a Quote of services Openbravo

Tags: configuration, openbravo

I have everything set up and I'm to the point of creating my first quote (Sales Order). The issue is that all my products are of the service category and I can't find a way of adding them to the quote. Only products are an option.

The services are already created.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to create a price list, a version of that price list and then link the service to the price list first.